# Refining the output of a forecast on a daily basis

Tags: forecasting, python, generalized-additive-model

I'm interested in modifying a monthly forecast on a recurring basis by including daily data. I'm experimenting with the Prophet tool opensourced by Facebook (https://github.com/facebookincubator/prophet) but I'm open to using other methods as this currently does not support the use of external regressors.

While I could forecast at a daily level using prophet (i.e. on the 15th day of the month, I feed in 14 days of data and predict the next 16) and aggregate the output, I've been told this compounds the errors rather than averaging them out. So I'm forecasting at a monthly level, but I need to modify that outlook on a regular basis based on data that keeps coming in.

Suggestions on models/methodologies I could be using to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to refine your question to make it narrower & more concrete. If your question amounts to "Suggestions?", people may consider that *too broad*.

Comment: hmm. alright, will edit it.